# How to get a Telegram Channel Id without sending a message to it

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is there any way to find a telegram channel id without sending a message to it ?

Right now I go this way and find the channel id by calling this URL in my code and get the JSON as result:
`https://api.telegram.org/bot???????/sendMessage?chat_id=@?????&text=123`

However, this cause sending the message "123" to the channel which is not good.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you

Answer (score 44):

Check [this link](https://github.com/GabrielRF/telegram-id) for help.
It is using web telegram url param info.

Adding details from the referred link:

1. log in [web telegram](https://web.telegram.org)
2. Click on the target channel then you will find the url displayed on your browser.

If it's a public channel, the ID is @name of the channel.

If it's a private channel then the url must be similar to:
`https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=c1018013852_555990343349619165`
For this case, the channel ID would be 1018013852.
It's important to know that channel's IDs are always negative and 13 characters long!
So add -100 to it, making the correct ID -1001018013852.

Answer (score 16):

You Can use Web Telegram to see each channel id in link of that page in your explorer
or

Just Simply Forward a message from your channel to This Bot: (https://telegram.me/getidsbot)

Comment: Good Answer, But unfortunately the `Bot` not answering.
I am using (https://telegram.me/telebot_robot)[@telebot_robot] that works perfect

Comment: GetIDs Bot works fine at the moment. If not, one can deploy a new copy of the bot: https://github.com/wjclub/telegram-bot-getids .
As a backup, here is my bot on AWS Lambda (which means that it's free to maintain): https://t.me/itpp_myid_bot

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just forward a message of the channel to your bot and get the `message.forward_from_chat.id`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Get your channel link
2. install python library [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon)
3. get your api_id and api_hash [here](https://my.telegram.org/auth).
4. write the following code and run:

   ```
    from telethon import TelegramClient
    api_id=
    api_hash=
    channel_link = 'your_channel_link'
    client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash,
                            update_workers=4, spawn_read_thread=False)
    client.start()
    entity = client.get_input_entity(**channel_link**)
    print(entity.channel_id)
   ```

By the way, if you use it for telegram bot, just add -100 before the printed id, this should be work!

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'channel_id'`

Answer (score 0):

Fixing @scruel's answer:

```
In [1]: api_id = ...                                                                                                                                  

In [2]: api_hash = '...'                                                                                                     

In [3]: channelLink = 'https://t.me/BTCST_Community_EN'                                                                                                   

In [4]: from telethon import TelegramClient, events                                                                                                       

In [5]: client = TelegramClient('test', api_id, api_hash)                                                                                                 

In [6]: client.start()                                                                                                                                    
Out[6]: <telethon.client.telegramclient.TelegramClient at 0x7fc90c352290>

In [7]: entity = await client.get_entity(channelLink)                                                                                                     

In [8]: channelId = '-100' + str(entity.id)                                                                                                               

In [9]: channelId                                                                                                                                        
Out[9]: '-1001236496320'
```

Here's a CLI util to do it:

```py
#!env/bin/python

import sys
import asyncio

from telethon import TelegramClient

import config

async def channel_id_from_link(client, channel_link):
    return "-100" + str((await client.get_entity(channel_link)).id)

async def main(channel_link):
    async with TelegramClient(
        "test", config.api_id, config.api_hash
    ) as client:
        channel_id = await channel_id_from_link(client, channel_link)

    return channel_id

if __name__ == "__main__":
    channel_link = sys.argv[1]
    channel_id = asyncio.run(main(channel_link))
    print(channel_id)
```

Test:

```
> ./TelegramChannelId.py https://t.me/binance_api_english
-1001134190352
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your bot into your channel and go to https://api.telegram.org/bot/getUpdates.

If someone send message to that channel, you will get the channel ID there.